# Display MS Document file using apache poi library android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am able to read the xls document but I don't know how to display it in my application. Do anyone have idea how to display MS Document files using apache poi library?
I have tried searching on google, everywhere only how to read document is mentioned not how to display these document. I don't want to modify the data inside document,Just want to display it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Do you need to display same like xls in android..???

Comment: yes, Do you know how to do it? or is there any other ways to display these documents

Comment: https://github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

The [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) does not display documents in Android. It is for reading and writing those files, not displaying them. Quoting the mission statement:

> The Apache POI Project's mission is to create and maintain Java APIs for manipulating various file formats based upon the Office Open XML standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE 2 Compound Document format (OLE2). In short, you can read and write MS Excel files using Java. In addition, you can read and write MS Word and MS PowerPoint files using Java. Apache POI is your Java Excel solution (for Excel 97-2008). We have a complete API for porting other OOXML and OLE2 formats and welcome others to participate.

Comment: Thanks,then what should I use to display MS documents inside my application?

Comment: @unflagged.destination: A search engine search on `android display microsoft word library` turns up several options.

Comment: I searched a lot but can't find one through which I can display office documents inside my application. I only get how to read these documents not how to display.

Comment: No,I opted another solution of converting all MS files to pdf and then showing it in my application.

Comment: @unflagged.destination What library do you use to convert office files to PDF ?